# Can someone give me more insight between the difference of 'Contrast' and 'Compare'?

Tags: differences

When we juxtapose two things and compare them i.e 'Xbox and PS4 ; how do they compare?'  are we looking for which one is better? Somewhat by the same token, when we say 'Mastercard and Visa card ; how do they contrast' what are we insinuating ?

> I saw that compare doesn't necessarily mean that we look at similarities between the two/more things , so why use 'contrast' at  all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [quick dictionary search](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contrast) shows **contrast** means:

> to set off in contrast : compare or appraise in respect to differences

**Compare** means:

> to examine the character or qualities of especially in order to
>   discover resemblances or differences

So while the two terms are similar, there are subtle differences between compare and contrast. Specifically, contrast deals only with the differences between things.

Comment: I understand but I saw in the question linked above as well as your provided definiton that *compare* doesn't only refer to looking at similarities. So why are we using contrast? So has the term '*compare* been generalized and should be used only to refer to when looking at similarities between things to determine which is the best amongst them.

Comment: I'd argue both terms are essentially the same. However, some definitions of compare focuses only on similarities. Additional discussion from Merriam-Webster (cited above) states,  "COMPARE is used for showing the likenesses between two or more things." Thus, compare AND contrast would remove any ambiguity.

Comment: I might slightly suggest that 'contrast' might be used more to draw inferences about the ~nature~ of things  ~how~ how thing differ for the purpose of noticing -  while compare is more about ~alternatives~   Compare prices,  compare travel routes.  Comparing prices from store to store notices differences too.  I can't put my finger on it precisely but the idea that contrast also refers to  accentuating elements in art provides a clue.  If one were to "contrast prices between stores" there would be a suggestion you were diving into a business model conversation, not bargain shopping.